# C# UWP CryptographicEngine.Encrypt() returns null

Tags: c#, encryption, uwp, aes, encryption-symmetric

I trying to encrypt input bytes[] to AES, but final encryption buffer is null.

```
private byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data)
{
    byte[] secretKey = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };

    IBuffer key = Convert.FromBase64String(Convert.ToBase64String(secretKey.ToArray()).ToString()).AsBuffer();
    Debug.WriteLine(key.Length);
    SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider algorithmProvider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbc);
    CryptographicKey cryptographicKey = algorithmProvider.CreateSymmetricKey(key);
    IBuffer bufferEncrypt = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(cryptographicKey, data.AsBuffer(), null);

    return bufferEncrypt.ToArray();
}
```

Debugger show local variables as (Name, Value, Type):

```
+       this    {Project.Auth}  Project.Auth
+       data    {byte[15]}  byte[]
    bufferEncrypt   null    Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer
+       cryptographicKey    {Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.CryptographicKey}   Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.CryptographicKey
+       key {System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeBuffer}    Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer {System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeBuffer}
+       algorithmProvider   {Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider}  Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider
+       SecretKey   Count = 16  System.Collections.Generic.List<byte>
```

Where is my fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I even cannot run your code snippet successfully on my side, exception `System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.` will be thrown when `CreateSymmetricKey(key)`. Your key seems to be the wrong length, the key length should be a certain number of bits long based on the security you need. (256 bits for AES is common).

In additional, CBC algorithms require an initialization vector, you could assign a random number for the vector. More details please reference [Symmetric keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/cryptographic-keys)
.

Please try to fix your issue and implement the encrypt feature by following the [official sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Cryptography-and-3305467b) or [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetrickeyalgorithmprovider).

Comment: Thanks, i changed code to:
            string aesKey = Convert.ToBase64String(secretKey);
            IBuffer key = Convert.FromBase64String(aesKey).AsBuffer();
            SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider algorithmProvider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbc);
            CryptographicKey ckey = algorithmProvider.CreateSymmetricKey(key);

            IBuffer buffEncrypt = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(ckey, data.AsBuffer(), null);
            return buffEncrypt.ToArray();

And it's work